# Calling an Apex action inside a HTML in Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, apexactionfunction

I need to call an apex action inside HTML.
I had completed my UI design in Visualforce page with the help of HTML, now i need to call my action from controller (Custom).

I am not sure how to insert the apex action inside HTML. I couldn't find any blog or solution for the same.

Please find the sample code below, I need to achieve the same.

```
<div class="WholeBoxSmallDiv" id="NewSmallDiv" style="display:none">
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="5%"><img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.offerIMG)}"/></td>
        <td class="classBold">Search Offer</td>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!searchList}" rerender="formId">
    <apex:param name="objType" assignTo="{!strObjectType}" value="Case"/>
    </apex:actionsupport>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But the code is not working.

Please let me know if anyone else have achieved the same.

Comment: Can you please post the code from your controller too?

Comment: On which html element you want the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this thru Javascript

HTML -> call Javascript -> call Apex

Reference : [JavaScript Remoting and Static HTML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_approaches_remoting.htm)

> Add JavaScript functions to the page as handlers to respond to user
>   interaction. Use JavaScript remoting to call Apex @RemoteAction
>   methods that retrieve records, perform DML, and so on.

and here's an example with code from salesforce developer docs

[JS Remoting Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm)

Comment: Thank you , i am trying to call a Java script from HTML and then invoke an apex function.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am trying to call apex action function from HTML through JAVA script.  HTML--->JavaScript--->Apex Action. However this is not working. Currently the call is going till JavaScript but the action is not called. please find the scripts in my next comment.

Comment: 'Javascript :

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function CheckoffersJavaScript()
    {    
        Checkoffersmethod() ;
        alert('Entered Javascript') ;
    }
</script>

Apex action:

<apex:actionfuntion name="Checkoffersmethod" action="{!checkOffersBasedOnEmailOrVIN}" status="mySaveStatus1" rerender="formId">
             <apex:param name="objType" assignTo="{!strObjectType}" value="Case"/> 
 </apex:actionfuntion>  '

Comment: HTML:

 '<div class="WholeBoxSmallDiv" id="NewSmallDiv" style="display:none">
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="5%"><img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.offerIMG)}"/></td>
            <td class="classBold" onclick="CheckoffersJavaScript">Search Offer</td>
              </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>'